# How to convert milliseconds to seconds with separator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a practice bridging map for me, and need to convert milliseconds to seconds, but with a separator.

Example:

| Milliseconds | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | 0.050 |
| 150 | 0.150 |
| 4900 | 4.900 |
| 28769500 | 28769.500 |

The values in the result column is what I want. I want the result to show in the action bar.

Using datapack and 1.16 Minecraft version.

Scoreboard objectives:

| Objective | Description |
| --- | --- |
| bridgingTickTime | bridging time in tick |
| bridgingTime | bridging time in milliseconds |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objectives are internally an integer, meaning you can't natively store floating point on them. Instead, you want to create two objectives to store the integer part and the decimal part and then show them.

You can also use fake names (invalid Minecraft names using symbols) to store those values instead of having different scoreboards. In my example, I have a score called `Time` and three variables, `$Time`, `$TimeSI` (Time in seconds, integer part) and `$TimeSD` (Seconds, decimal part). Unfortunately, to make math operations, you need to have a variable with said value, meaning we need one for `1000` and `-1` as constants to be able to do said task. Here is how it looks

After creating the scoreboard, store the constants:

```
scoreboard players set $1000 time 1000
scoreboard players set $-1 time -1
```

Then, we copy the `$Time` to `$TimeSI` and divide by 1000 (The decimal part will disappear due to the data type), followed by `$TimeSD` getting `$TimeSI`'s value, multiplying by -1000 and subtracting from `$Time`. Here is the snippet for it:

```
execute store result score $TimeSI time run scoreboard players get $Time time
scoreboard players operation $TimeSI time /= $1000 time

execute store result score $TimeSD time run scoreboard players get $TimeSI time
scoreboard players operation $TimeSI time *= $1000 time
scoreboard players operation $TimeSI time *= $-1 time
scoreboard players operation $TimeSI time += $Time time
```

And here is the title command to show the value using the action bar:

```
 title @a actionbar [{"score":{"name":"$TimeSI", "objective":"time"}},{"text":"."},{"score":{"name":"$TimeSD", "objective":"time"}}]
```

Comment: I was just thinking, there's no way players can get 0.050 seconds of time, thanks you so much!